# Blazor app hosted in IIS is not rendering anything on the page

Tags: .net, iis, blazor, blazor-server-side

I've followed the steps for hosting a .NET Blazor application multiple times now in IIS and keep running into the same issue where the app seems to load, but nothing actually renders.

To be clear, I have done the following:

- installed the .NET Core Runtime on the remote machine
- installed the Hosting Bundle on the remote machine
- published the Blazor application
- moved the publish folder to the remote machine
- configured the application as a new Site
- referenced the app's publish folder's physical path
- configured the Application Pool, No Managed Code, all that

Now, when everything is configured and spun up, I can navigate to the site, but nothing is being rendered. When I F12 to debug, I'm shown this markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="mysite.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!--Blazor:{"sequence":1,"type":"server","descriptor":"CfDJ8KNqOmGyWyhPhIIFwukK1C/CnKpDLhpYQZqSNqT0Z3du\u002Be1r4DsBAeNEyocAzmxKbOFsO1aYADSLcTUItO1JIvurbvcT3FBFjoWJ8THw/fK09yKdQ2uTdUOyM0c0wHWNDt8Ld2FxpnMSvHIfDChdEBoYNK6mr4RaWPY5eZVa7P5lSisk2bF\u002BKoEqLmLTqWwmcZZVPvziHvaD3Rgxp/JuGB15UIJSwEdrjW2r8xBgRZKQqn4gR7EBsB0QsCLYnM9/J8QmyhA20s9oNbwuVKtjyvmILVOnUZ0JpemM\u002BJQ3RfzNgxF\u002B28ANPxpNJC14MfaLMJQ4utcU/xcCS/\u002BzDaM5HguhXxZMnNJI2MIbL4LhxpLoB3/93krxzK8x9NBtsj8vB9wHIo7ODkCCweYouLWpeWHSVltbW3WmIC7SgvF3FPn5"}-->


</head>
<body>
    
<!--Blazor:{"sequence":0,"type":"server","descriptor":"CfDJ8KNqOmGyWyhPhIIFwukK1C8ohNoHAz/Z481LO5ATRXyA9JaqSOzKBE412QFZEQt4p6UBA6ikaOkcqbuDqs1MIdWBeIc7XWweyGhv4S\u002Beb/nFnncgyj6yz07\u002B4DkPKt46iSvn/vsYZsMVzNf0DIu5AAr2O0GzxpRVHtDiqcueozZZvraWAyFWw6PYf\u002ByyMgYEWQ5rDcm2kup2kANZcbofIkZe3Dz4WPwPfax7JMAuYYPi9v\u002Bwub9jAOy8X0MVxx95M1eU8z1QvaYCjS4KoGt\u002BtYnaljK4gocB2lx5\u002BDHgJkFxJ2wgj4ZH3dJV\u002BKdwsd8qlJchAG3xCE4sRpWUAimM33QLWrLt4GQuJ8\u002BhRI3mpgRV"}-->


    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

So it seems as though I'm accessing *something*, but none of the code that actually renders any of my site is running. I have confirmed that the site works perfectly fine on IIS Express in Visual Studio.

I am seeing nothing of use in my event viewer, no errors in the browser console.

Please advise if further information about my situation would be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried publishing the default Blazor site?  I suspect you're missing some lines in Startup.cs.

Comment: I tried deploying a default Blazor website locally and everything works fine, I can't reproduce your issue. Please try republishing your project to make sure the content is up to date, you can refer this blog to deploy: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/deploying-a-blazor-application-on-iis/ and please enable stdoutLogEnabled="true" to check the logs.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 NET 6.0 doesn't include a `Startup.cs`

@YurongDai In referencing this blog and going through the process several times, I narrowed it down to the fact that js interop is a cruel mistress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In going through the publish/deploy process several times, I narrowed down my issue to JS Interop problems within the application. At some point early on in development, I had swapped the render mode from `ServerPreRendered` to `Server` to test out some JS Interop functions. Ultimately I had to refactor that functionality so that I could have all of my components initialize correctly while making async calls to js functions.

At any rate, I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: I'm glad your problem was solved, if you can mark your answer later, it will lead more people in the right direction.